# 429 Too Many Requests Error While Running Mocha Test - NodeJS / Swagger API

Tags: node.js, http, mocha.js, swagger

I used swagger (swagger.io) to built my app's API and everything works fine in production environment. However, when I ran some mocha tests on these APIs, I keep getting this error regarding status code 429 Too Many Requests:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Too Many Requests
    at Request.callback (..../node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:698:17)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (..../node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:922:12)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:926:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
```

Usually this error happens after I ran the mocha test twice in a row (ie start throwing this error from the third time onwards). I suspected I was overloading my localhost server, but the error persisted even after I closed and reopened the server.

Would be super grateful if someone could point me towards the right direction to solve this problem.

Comment: It seems you have rate limiting implemented into your app. Check your middlewares for any rate limiting libraries.

Comment: @tcooc Thanks for replying. I tried using npm express-rate-limit and maximised each window (1 minute) to 100 requests but still couldn't make it work

Comment: Rate limiting is the possible problem, not the solution. What you should have been doing is checking if it exists and removing it.

Comment: @cchoi how you solved this, I ran in similar problem can you please help

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using the express-rate-limit with some environment variables that are probably missing during tests. In this case the rateLimiter will try using the default values (according to their [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit):

- windowMs: 60000 (1 minute)
- max: 5 (requests))

So when you see the error message it'll show something like **Request velocity exceeded (6 out of 5 max requests)**

So what you can do is setting your default value, in case your variables are undefined. Or you can set them in your testing files.
For the first approach, you can have something like the following:

```
const rateLimit = require("express-rate-limit")
const rateLimiter = rateLimit({
    windowMs: process.env.REQUEST_VELOCITY_WINDOW || 60000,
    max: process.env.REQUEST_VELOCITY_LIMIT || 1000,
    handler: (req, res) => {
        console.error(
            `Request velocity exceeded (${req.rateLimit.current} out of ${req.rateLimit.limit} max requests) ${req.ip} - ${req.url}`
        )
        res.status(429).send("Request velocity exceeded")
    },
})
```